# Mysql query to truncate data while inserting

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I've created a table like this :

```
create table tbl(
address varchar(5000));
```

If i want to insert data in to the field **address**, if the length of data inserted  exceeds the length of the field **address**. Then first truncate the the data and insert it in to **address**.
please give me the correct query for the above problem....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested on my mysql (5.5.8), create table as follows:

```
create table test ( a varchar(10) );
```

then insert

```
insert into test(a) values('1234567890112');
```

then select

```
select * from test;
```

gives me `1234567890`

I think mysql will automatically truncate anything bigger you pass in to the field, so you don't need to worry, unless you need to log it in your application level everytime that happens

Comment: Yes you'r right, but you can too configure MySQL do not truncate and message an error when data is too long then field length, I have this situation now and looking for that config to disable it)

Answer (score 2):

your insert/update query should probably call a method truncate which looks like this:

```
public static String truncate(String value, int length)
{
  if (value != null && value.length() > length)
    value = value.substring(0, length);
  return value;
}
```

Hope this helps.